# Kotlin, targeting Java interop: Idiomatic type for lazy collection?

Tags: kotlin, lazy-evaluation, kotlin-interop

When targeting Java interop, what type should one use for a lazy collection?

- [`Sequence<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence/index.html) makes the most sense for Kotlin callers due to extension functions on it being lazy by default, but forces Java callers to deal with a Kotlin stdlib type and convert the sequence iterator manually (sequence does not extend iterable!)
- [`Iterable<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-iterable/index.html) makes sense for Java callers due to implicit usage in for loops, but will cause unsuspecting Kotlin callers to accidentally drop laziness due to non-lazy extension functions
- [`Stream<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) is optimal for both Java and Kotlin callers but may have overhead and is Java 8+ (Kotlin targets 6+)

Comment: May be you can use iterable with `someIterable.asSequence()` in Kotlin?

Comment: That world work, but leaves - as stated - the possibility that an *unsuspecting* caller accidentally drops laziness. This question is more in direction library development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make everyone happy by implementing all three. e.g.:

```
data class User(val name: String)

fun userSequence(): Sequence<User> = TODO()
fun usersLazily(): Iterable<User> = userSequence().asIterable()
fun userStream(): Stream<User> = userSequence().asStream()
```

By not using a simple name like `users` for any of these functions you make the caller think just a little extra on which one they really want:

- Kotlin users will use `userSequence`.
- Java 1.6 and 1.7 users will use `usersLazily`.
- Java 1.8 users will use `userStream`.

`userStream` will have to be defined in a separate JAR adding JDK 1.8 support to your 1.6/1.7 JAR (similar to how `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8` does for `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib`).

With that said, I would question whether you really need to maintain Java 1.6 or 1.7 support. If you find you don't then you can put `userSequence` and `userStream` into the same JAR and not even define `usersLazily`.

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll accept this in a day or two if there are no alternative ideas.